# Bullet is not working in phaser.io

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I want to fire bullet from the my object. Everything is looking right but after a lot of struggle not getting a proper reason. Have a look of my code.

**Game.js**

```js
var Game = {
    preload : function() {

        // spaceship image screen
        this.load.image('spaceship', './assets/images/spaceship.png');
        //Load the bullet
        this.load.image('bullet',   'assets/images/bullet.png');

    },
```

This is the create function

```js
create : function() {
    //  Our bullet group
    bullets = game.add.group();
    bullets.enableBody = true;
    bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
    bullets.createMultiple(30, 'bullet', 0, false);
    bullets.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
    bullets.setAll('anchor.y', 0.5);
    bullets.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
    bullets.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);

    sprite = game.add.sprite(400, 300, 'spaceship');
    sprite.anchor.set(0.5);
},
```

This is the update function

```js
update: function() {
    if (game.input.activePointer.isDown)
    {
        this.fire();
    }
},
```

The fire function

```js
fire: function () {

    if (game.time.now > nextFire && bullets.countDead() > 0)
    {
        nextFire = game.time.now + fireRate;

        var bullet = bullets.getFirstDead();

        bullet.reset(sprite.x - 80, sprite.y - 80);

        game.physics.arcade.moveToPointer(bullet, 300);
    }
}
```

Please review my code and suggest where I am wrong?

Comment: What actually happens? Does the bullet appear but not move? Does it move, but not in the right direction? Does the fire function ever get called?

Comment: Right now it's working. I was changing background in update and my bullet group was in create , i put my bullet group in update and its working fine. But i want to change starting point of bullet if i change in 
bullets.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
bullets.setAll('anchor.y', 0.5); 
increase from 0.5 to more so i am getting error. So please help me i want to start bullet at the top of the spaceship.

Comment: You've accepted an answer but it appears you're asking a question in it. Is your issue resolved, or do you still have a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can not spot the problem with the informations I have here ... is there any reason you are not using the pre-build weapon class? There are good examples on the phaser examples site.